# Could not find a part of the path 'C:\inetpub\AspNetCoreWebApps\app\EmailTemplates\example.cshtml'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, sendgrid, hangfire

I'm building a notification service using ASP.NET Core where i have to send emails. I've an authentication service that makes an HTTP call to the notification service to send the emails. I'm also using Hangfire for the background tasks. I discover that when i make call to the notification service to send the emails i get this error when deployed to IIS both locally and in AWS Elastic Beanstalk

> > > Could not find a part of the path 'C:\inetpub\AspNetCoreWebApps\app\EmailTemplates\example.cshtml'.

The background job tries to resend the enqueued mail and sometimes after 5-20 minutes the mails are sent.

Here is my controller action for sending emails.

```
        [HttpPost("SendConfirmationMail")]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public IActionResult SendConfirmationMail([FromBody] EmailModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return new ObjectResult(new NotificationResponse
                {
                    Status = "Error",
                    ResponseCode = 400,
                    Data = null,
                    ResponseMessage = ModelState
                });

            var jobId = backgroundJobClient.Enqueue( () => emailService
                .SendConfirmEmail(model.RecipientEmail, model.FirstName, model.LastName, model.CallbackUrl));
            return new ObjectResult(new NotificationResponse
            {
                Status = "Success",
                ResponseCode = 200,
                Data = $"Job Id: {jobId}",
                ResponseMessage = "Processing Request..."
            });
        }
```

Here is the FluentEmail method the action calls

```
        public async Task SendConfirmEmail(string recipientEmail, string firstName, string 
                              lastName, string callbackUrl)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
                {
                    var mailer = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IFluentEmail>();
                    var email = mailer
                        .To(recipientEmail, firstName)
                        .Subject("Confirm Email")
                        .UsingTemplateFromFile($"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}/EmailTemplates/ConfirmEmail.cshtml",
                        new
                        {
                            FirstName = firstName,
                            LastName = lastName,
                            CallbackUrl = callbackUrl
                        });

                    await email.SendAsync();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
            
        }
```

How can i go about resolving this problem?

Comment: Ensure your template file and folder is in the bin folder and your template is set to Content in file properties.

Comment: Thanks @AliK, i just checked by bin folder and i can't find the templates. How do i go about adding them to the bin folder?

Comment: You would normally sent this from the properties window the bottom left and select the file in the solution Explorer.

Comment: @Alik I have added the Email Templates folder to the bin folder and deployed to IIS but i still get that error. This is the way it works, When i make a request to that endpoint sometimes the mail are sent immediately and sometimes it fails showing me that error response. What could possibly cause that problem?

Comment: I can't see a scenario where it would give you that error randomly and then work other times.  I would say its either working or not?  Otherwise another option is to clean the IIS folder where you  deployed and do a fresh copy there.  How are you deploying to IIS?

Comment: I'm deploying to AWS Elastic Beanstalk which supports IIS as a server for .NET

Comment: Not sure how beanstalk does it but maybe an older version is cached

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution to the problem. I removed the background job on the notification service and configured it on the email sending action on the authentication service. This resolved the problem i was faced with. That worked for me. This problem is a generic one you may have to find the use case.
One of such instance where you would experience this problem is if you have not copied .cshtml file into the deployment folder. You can do this by adding this to the .csproj file.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <CopyRazorGenerateFilesToPublishDirectory>true</CopyRazorGenerateFilesToPublishDirectory>
```

That would allow the .cshtml file compile when published to the deployment folder.

Another tweak would be to add the .cshtml file to the bin folder. Do this by right clicking on .cshtml file, go to properties and on Build Action, select Content and on Copy to output directory select Copy always.
That should do the work but remember the problem could emanate from something else.